# How to make fingerprint reader more reliable?

Tags: 16.04, fingerprint-reader

I'm using fingerprint-gui, and it works, however it is awfully unreliable. I have to sweep my finger many, many, many times until my finger will be identified. I didn't find much complains about it so... maybe there is a better software for this? Or maybe there are some tricks that would make fingerprint authentication more reliable, that I don't know about?

PS. I'm using Lenovo ThinkPad x250